# Styling of a Lightning Web Component with shadows and padding

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am fairly new to lwc development. I want to style a text so that it appears as a regular lightning component.
Everything is working well ... except the styling.
[image]

I want that the box does have a shadow and that the label and the "Not available" will be indented like the following "Key Facts" component.
Here is the code of the markup:

```
<template>
<template if:true={noWorkspaceId}>
        <div class="slds-box box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px silver;">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked slds-m-left_small">
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">{label}</span>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__static slds-text-color_error">{notAvailable}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
<template>
```

I have tried to use padding or a margin but it does not work. Furthermore I am unable to add a shadow.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Kindly look into https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in this line:
`<div class="slds-box box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px silver;">`

You cannot add inline style in `class` attribute. You could use `style` attribute, but a better choice would be rely on slds classes like `.slds-tabs_card`, here's the [specs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#As-a-Card).

Change `<div class="slds-box box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px silver;">` to `<div class="slds-tabs_card">` in order to get the box shadowing and some padding.

The "Key Facts" component is a [tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example) and that tab starts with a [card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example) element.
You might not need a tabset if you have only one tab.

So to achieve that style the code should be:

```
<div class="slds-tabs_card">
    <lightning-tabset class="slds-text-heading_small">
        <lightning-tab label={label}>
            <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title={label} icon-name="standard:account">
                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:down" variant="border-filled" alternative-text="Show More" slot="actions">
                </lightning-button-icon>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-color_error">{notAvailable}</p>
            </lightning-card>
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben. Workes like a charm!.